# Last modification time of Java resource within a jar

Tags: java, jar, resources, last-modified

I need to get last modification time of a java resource. When I use

```
url.openConnection().getLastModified()
```

it returns the last modification time of the entire jar (same for all items inside), but I need modification time of particular files. The information is there (when I open the jar as a zip, I see the correct time at the particular files). Does someone know how to access it?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Maintaining zipped files Modified Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983301/java-maintaining-zipped-files-modified-date)

Comment: [Try this and see if it work for you. ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/how-do-i-list-the-files-inside-a-jar-file

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to query the JAR content, using JarInputStream. 
YOu will be iterate over the entries, and get objects of [ZipEntry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html).
One of the accessor methods of ZipEntry is [getTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#getTime%28%29). 
I Belive this is the method you're seeking.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
try (FileSystems jarFS = FileSystems.newFileSystem(URI.create("jar:" + jarURI), Collections.<String, Object>emptyMap())){
    Path resourcePath = jarFS.getPath(resourcePathString); 
    FileTime fileTime = Files.getLastModifiedTime(resourcePath);
}
```

I also have written soem utility methods to work with Jar files using the NIO File API:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/0.2/docs/api/softsmithy-lib-core/org/softsmithy/lib/nio/file/JarFiles.html

The library is Open Source.

Maven:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.softsmithy.lib</groupId>  
    <artifactId>softsmithy-lib-core</artifactId>  
    <version>0.2</version>   
</dependency>
```